# Was Nick Fury treated with GH-325?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

During Captain America: The Winter Soldier...

Nick Fury recovers from multiple gunshot wounds to the abdomen within a relatively short space of time.
Whilst we are shown him in an injured but stable position, was there any indication that the GH-325 drug from *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* was used on him?

[image: vials of GH-325]

I don't recall seeing a shot that identified its use during this sequence, but why set up something like a 'miracle cure' with the series only to discard it for the film?

[GH-325](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/GH.325) (which uses Kree blood [told ya' so!, check the rollbacks] as one of its components) regenerates dead tissue and, according to the series, is administered to Coulson under direct orders from Nick Fury, establishing he knows about its existence and healing properties.

Countering this, however, *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D* Episode 18 features a scene in which Agent May informs Coulson the reason she was ordered to set up a direct line with Fury was because the Director feared that (as GH-325 was developed under Hydra's supervision) Coulson's use of the drug could have somehow compromised him to Hydra's control.

If this was a plausible concern, why would Fury be happy to use the substance?

Is there another explanation that covers Fury's startling recovery?

Comment: I personally think writers didn't give half as much thoughts as you did into this. IMHO Nick Fury recovered because his badass level is Samuel L. Jackson. :)

Comment: @Crono While I would generally support your opinion (and still think it to be the most likely answer), the *MCU*'s seemingly high attention to details and cross-movie consistency makes this a not so uninteresting question.

Comment: @Crono, I'd love it if not only did Fury not require the medical equipment he was hooked up to, his proximity to it actually improved its efficiency. Marvel are big on convergence at the minute, it seems almost like the purpose of setting up GH-325 was to use it as a plot device in the Movies to circumvent people moaning about 'magic potions', rewarding the fans that participate in the wider universe. But I don't think they made the connection overtly in the film... did they?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm not saying the question isn't worth an answer. I'm just saying that I don't believe writers, as devoted to details as they can be, really cares how heroes recovers from appearantly fatal injuries. Or from being tested by G-force in a falling glass dome. Or from pretty much every bones in the body breaking up from being oh-so violently (and oh-so funnily) tossed around by giant green freaks. ;)

Comment: Doesn't the source of GH-325 get destroyed when the AOS team leave the "House" (or Home, or whatever it was called -- the secret place where Coleson discovers the source of GH-325)? I would think the only quantity left was used on Sky, but I guess that is an unknown.

Comment: Well, he did go to the same place so i say he did

Comment: @Keen, When *GotG* comes out, and it's confirmed that the alien was indeed Kree; will you reverse this latest edit ;)

Answer (score 8):

Having just re-watched Captain America: Winter Soldier, there is no on-screen evidence to show that Nick Fury was treated with GH-325 from what I saw.  I am also dubious that Fury would treat himself with something that he knew caused a lot of problems to those that it was used on unless their mind was completely wiped.

So unless they do some sort of retcon, I think it's safe to say he wasn't.